# Performance issue after migrating from codeless KEXT to DEXT

Tags: macos, libusb, iokit, kernel-extension, driverkit

I am working on migrating a codeless KEXT to DriverKit. It is used to disable the IOKit HID driver for USB devices that present themselves as HID compliant in firmware upgrade mode.

So far I have managed to match an empty subclass of `IOService` to the relevant devices.
Here's an example of the `IOKitPersonalities` entries I'm using:

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifierKernel</key>
    <string>com.apple.kpi.iokit</string>
    <key>IOClass</key>
    <string>IOUserService</string>
    <key>IOProviderClass</key>
    <string>IOUSBHostInterface</string>
    <key>IOResourceMatch</key>
    <string>IOKit</string>
    <key>IOUserClass</key>
    <string>DriverKitTestExtension</string>
    <key>IOUserServerName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>bConfigurationValue</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>idVendor</key>
    <integer><!-- USB Vendor ID --></integer>
    <key>idProduct</key>
    <integer><!-- USB Product ID --></integer>
</dict>
```

Is it correct to use `IOUSBHostInterface` as the provider class for this use case? I've also tried using the old (deprecated) `IOUSBInterface`, but it has the same problems as `IOUSBHostInterface`.

The new DEXT is working but I am seeing some bad performance regressions in our firmware update code. Calls to libusb are taking tens of seconds. If I use the old KEXT, they return immediately.

Here are some example traces of the problem:

```
   5 redacted 3168.0  libusb_claim_interface ..../libusb/Sources/libusb/core.c:1310
   4 redacted 3168.0  darwin_claim_interface ..../libusb/Sources/libusb/darwin_usb.c:1089
   3 IOUSBLib 1668.0  IOUSBInterfaceClass::USBInterfaceOpen(bool)
   2 IOKit 1668.0  io_service_wait_quiet
   1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 1668.0  mach_msg
   0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 1668.0  mach_msg_trap
```

And:

```
   7 redacted 1859.0  libusb_get_device_list ..../libusb/Sources/libusb/core.c:632
   6 redacted 1859.0  darwin_get_device_list ..../libusb/Sources/libusb/darwin_usb.c:780
   5 redacted 1859.0  process_new_device ..../libusb/Sources/libusb/darwin_usb.c:726
   4 redacted 1766.0  darwin_check_configuration ..../libusb/Sources/libusb/darwin_usb.c:540
   3 IOKit 1766.0  IOIteratorNext
   2 IOKit 1766.0  io_iterator_next
   1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 1766.0  mach_msg
   0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 1766.0  mach_msg_trap
   0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 1766.0  mach_msg_trap
```

These are recorded in the "Time Profiler" instrument with "Record Waiting Threads" enabled.

Can I do anything in the DEXT to fix this problem? I've tried subclassing `IOUSBHostInterface` instead of `IOService`, but that made no difference.

Here's the relevant output from running "ioreg -lirc IOUSBHostInterface":

```
+-o IOUSBHostInterface@0  
  | {
  |   "USBSpeed" = 1
  |   "iInterface" = 0
  |   "IOServiceLegacyMatchingRegistryID" = 4294971983
  |   "bInterfaceProtocol" = 0
  |   "bAlternateSetting" = 0
  |   "idProduct" = 
  |   "bcdDevice" = 292
  |   "USB Product Name" = 
  |   "locationID" = 338690048
  |   "bInterfaceClass" = 3
  |   "bInterfaceSubClass" = 0
  |   "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"2d9786c6-9ef3-11d4-ad51-000a27052861"="IOUSBHostFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
  |   "USBPortType" = 0
  |   "bConfigurationValue" = 1
  |   "bInterfaceNumber" = 0
  |   "USB Vendor Name" = 
  |   "IOServiceDEXTEntitlements" = (("com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb"))
  |   "idVendor" = 
  |   "bNumEndpoints" = 2
  |   "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
  |   "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBInterface"
  | }
  | 
  +-o DriverKitTestExtension  
      {
        "IOClass" = "IOUserService"
        "CFBundleIdentifier" = 
        "IOProviderClass" = "IOUSBHostInterface"
        "IOUserServerCDHash" = "faa70138281d36b53946591685ccdceba4a5d638"
        "idProduct" = 
        "IOResourceMatch" = "IOKit"
        "bConfigurationValue" = 1
        "IOProbeScore" = 90000
        "IOMatchCategory" = "com.apple.null.driver"
        "IOUserServerName" = 
        "IOMatchedPersonality" = {"IOClass"="IOUserService","CFBundleIdentifier"=" ","IOProviderClass"="IOUSBHostInterface","IOUserServerCDHash"="faa70138281d36b53946591685ccdceba4a5d638","idProduct"=,"IOResourceMatch"="IOKit","bConfigurationValue"=1,"IOMatchCategory"="com.apple.null.driver","IOUserServerName"=,"idVendor"=,"CFBundleIdentifierKernel"="com.apple.kpi.iokit","bInterfaceNumber"=0,"IOUserClass"="DriverKitTestExtension"}
        "idVendor" = 
        "CFBundleIdentifierKernel" = "com.apple.kpi.iokit"
        "bInterfaceNumber" = 0
        "IOUserClass" = "DriverKitTestExtension"
      }
```

Any input is welcome!

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried changing the old codeless KEXT to use `IOUSBHostInterface` (like the DEXT) instead of `IOUSBInterface` for `IOProviderClass`. Performance was still fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem! After reading [How to set `com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb` entitlement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61634176/how-to-set-com-apple-developer-driverkit-transport-usb-entitlement), I decided to experiment with the entitlements for my DEXT. This made me realize that the DEXT was not being loaded at all.

I changed the DEXT entitlements from:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

To:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>idVendor</key>
            <integer><!-- USB Vendor ID --></integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

After this, the log message from my `IOService` subclass is now showing up (using `log stream` with `grep`). Performance during the firmware upgrade is back to normal.

Comment: I'm looking into writing a codeless dext to prevent a specific device from mounting using IOUSBMassStorageDriver, so that I can then access it via WebUSB. Were you successful in the end? Do you know if a codeless dext can be installed independently of an app? Any pointers on where to start?

Comment: @Gerrit Yes, I was able to prevent the standard IOKit HID drivers from matching specific USB vendor ID/product ID. 

I think you should post a new SO question instead of discussing here in the comments. If you link to your question from here, I'll see if I can answer.

Comment: As a side note, I don't know much about WebUSB, but I would be surprised if you would be allowed to access mass storage from a browser. 

This question might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162692/can-webusb-transfer-files-to-a-usb-mass-storage-device-or-act-like-dd

Comment: Thanks, that gives me hope! :) I want to prevent the IOKit MassStorage drivers from matching a specific USB vendor ID & product ID, in which case I should then be able to access it from WebUSB. I'm using https://github.com/stuartlynne/USBApp-updated as a start until I can obtain a DriverKit entitlement. If I run into any specific issues, I'll be sure to post a new question.

Comment: I was going to post a new SO question, but it appears several exist already:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63212902/migrating-a-codeless-kext-to-a-codeless-dext
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442970/migrating-from-codeless-kext-to-dext-usb-interfaces-disappeared
that would answer my question as well.