# How to set `com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb` entitlement?

Tags: usb, iokit, entitlements, macos-system-extension, driverkit

I am unsure about how to set the `com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb` key in my dext entitlements file. The Info.plist file already contains the `IOKitPersonalities` dictionary, and reading about the [`com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_driverkit_transport_usb) dictionary it looks like it should contains entries with the same information as the entries of `IOKitPersonalities`.

The [entitlements file](https://github.com/knightsc/USBApp/blob/bec3759eb05a10b25221f0fdd6f96939ed7d01c3/MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver/MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver.entitlements) for a project that is very similar to what is being shown in the [WWDC video about driver kit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/702/) sets this to:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb</key>
<true/>
```

When I set it to `<true/>`, the system extension starts. I do see some lines like this before I see log lines from the app:

```
...
2020-05-06 12:23:19.229709+0200 0x51ac2    Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: DK: IOUserServer(sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver-0x100002aad)::exit(CDHash check failed)
```

Should this entitlement just reflect what is in the `IOKitPersonalities` dictionary?

With the key completely removed I get:

```
...
2020-05-06 12:23:19.229709+0200 0x51ac2    Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: DK: IOUserServer(sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver-0x100002aad)::exit(CDHash check failed)
2020-05-06 12:23:19.253517+0200 0x51ac2    Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: DK: IOUserServer(sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver-0x100002aae)::exit(Entitlements check failed)
```

.. so I guess the key must be there.

I am viewing log lines related to the app with `log stream --source | grep MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated answer**
*As I have shipped some USB DriverKit based drivers, I've found that in practice it's slightly different than I originally stated in the answer, although my original answer matched Apple's documentation.*

Although Apple mentions both Product ID and Vendor ID in the documentation for the USB transport entitlement, in practice only the vendor ID is relevant for entitlements/code signing purposes. This means that if your driver needs to support any number of USB devices with vendor IDs 1234 and 2345 (Decimal! Usual notation for vendor IDs is hex, so don't forget to convert first!) you will need to include the following in your dext's entitlements:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>idVendor</key>
        <integer>1234</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>idVendor</key>
        <integer>2345</integer>
    </dict>
</array>
```

To be clear, that means the entitlement must be of the type **array** -> **dictionaries**, even if you only need to support one vendor ID.

The `idVendor` values listed must also be embedded in your provisioning profile by Apple, which is why you must include them when you apply for DriverKit entitlements. Note that the form only supports a single vendor ID, so if you need to support more than one you *must* list them all in the free-form text field.

**Update 2:**

Since mid/late 2022 Apple has been making certain DriverKit entitlements available to *all* members of the dev programme *without* special application, *for development signing only.* This includes the USB transport entitlement. The “free” version of this is in a wildcard form and consists of the string “*” instead of a number. When using a provisioning profile with this version of the entitlement, your dext’s entitlement file will also need to use the asterisk.

**Platforms**

Although [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_driverkit_transport_usb?language=objc) (which we have established above is also incorrect in other ways) only mentions macOS, *this entitlement is **also needed** for developing and deploying USBDriverKit based drivers **for iPadOS**.* Make sure to request it for all platforms relevant to your project when applying. The previous paragraph about the self-service wildcard development-only entitlement applies to iPadOS in all regards as well.

Comment: Great! Previously I saw `044079.960013 IOUSBHostInterface@0: IOUSBHostInterface::matchPropertyTable: The com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb entitlements property is malformed` but after adding the `idProductArray` variant that log line is no longer printed.

Comment: Yep, that's the line I was thinking of but couldn't find at short notice. :-)

Comment: We have received our DriverKit entitlements for our vendor ID. I was struggling with setting `com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb` properly. In the end what I needed was to add a dictionary with only the `idVendor` entry in it. Anything other than that would not be accepted.

(I am still running with SIP disabled and systemextensions developer on, so this might not work in the end...)

Comment: This thread helped me find my answer for another DEXT problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61818712/7445. Thanks!