# idVendor for apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, driverkit, macos-system-extension

I was reading this informative post
[How to set `com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb` entitlement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61634176/how-to-set-com-apple-developer-driverkit-transport-usb-entitlement)

I wanted to ask, where do I get this `idVendor` from? What should be its value ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the Vendor ID of the device your driver will be driving. Apple asks for this when you request DriverKit entitlements, and you are presumably specifying it in your dext's IOKit personality's matching dictionary.

Note that vendor IDs are conventionally written in hexadecimal, but plists (Info.plist and the entitlements file) use decimal notation for numbers, so make sure you convert the value first.

Comment: thank you Phil.
I am just interested in being called for any usb connected . 
do I still need to use the Vendor id field in entitlement or can  it be skipped with empty dictionary?

Comment: With SIP disabled, this should work, assuming you've set your matching dictionary appropriately. If you actually want to do this in a shipping driver, you'll need to get in touch with Apple, I don't know if they hand out blanket USB entitlements. Note that various built-in devices in Macs are USB based, so you may lose access to critical devices on your system if your driver gets loaded instead of the default driver.