# DriverKit Driver is failing to launch on iPadOS due to an entitlements check failure, what am I missing?

Tags: ios, swift, usb, iokit, driverkit

We have a DriverKit application connected to a Teensy 4.1. The driver works fine on macOS, but we're attempting to get it working in iPadOS. Everything builds, the driver seems to be installing correctly, and I've enabled it in settings. Upon connecting the Teensy, it locates the correct dext and tries to launch it, but then fails with error:

`DK: CDCDriver-0x100002543: provider entitlements check failed`

I've done my best to verify we have entitlements configured correctly but I'm new to DriverKit and it's not clear to me what I'm missing. Could be something obvious.

We have targets for iOS and macOS. We're using different code signing and entitlements in the build settings for each SDK.

The local entitlements plist file for the iPadOS built driver is just:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit.communicates-with-drivers</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've also tried adding/removing `App Sandbox = YES` based on Apple's example project to no avail.

ID Capabilities enabled for the driver on developer.apple.com:

- DriverKit (Development)
- DriverKit Communicates with Drivers
- DriverKit USB Transport (Development)

Signing identity on iOS is Apple Development.

Provisioning Profile was set to DriverKit App Development with the above mentioned ID and capabilities.

The bundle ID prefix is the same as the parent app.

Any obvious mistakes here or ideas of things I could check?

Comment: You'll need to [add the USB transport entitlement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61634322/48660) and remove the "`communicates-with-drivers`" one from the dext, and instead add "`communicates-with-drivers`" to the app. (And yes, the latter is totally different from macOS. However, the USB transport entitlement is needed on macOS too unless you have special `boot-args` set or SIP disabled. A dext that uses only frameworks available on both platforms and that is set up correctly for vanilla macOS should work unmodified on iPadOS.)

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I do think it's worth pointing out that this error message seems to be coming from the kernel, which is [helpfully open source](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/main/iokit/Kernel/IOUserServer.cpp#L2678).

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I had tried adding the USB transport entitlement at one point (and we have it in the macOS version of the entitlements), but it caused an invalid code signature error and failed to build on the iPad. Turns out it was the issues you mentioned in that thread, @pmdj. I assumed it wasn't needed on iOS because the documentation says macOS only, which as you said is wrong. Just needed to change the idVendor to an * and remove the idProduct altogether. I did indeed have SIP disabled which answers why it worked on mac and not iOS. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, note you'll need to specify your actual vendor ID(s) in the entitlement for anything but development signing. DriverKit entitlements for non-development signing purposes must be  requested from Apple via their form. Make sure to specify all the signing scenarios (App Store, Ad Hoc, Developer ID, Enterprise, and/or Development) you're planning to use if you haven't already requested them. It can take some weeks to get them. I've now also added a proper answer with the solution. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a USB driver you need to [add the USB transport entitlement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61634322/48660). When using the self-serve default development USB transport entitlement, you need to set the Vendor ID to a string containing just an asterisk to match the provisioning profile, and leave the Product ID out of the entitlements altogether. For a release build that you deploy with ad hoc or app store (or on macOS Developer ID) signing, you'll need to request the entitlement for the relevant purposes and platforms from Apple and match the granted provisioning profile's vendor ID value(s). This is identical to how it's done on macOS, and indeed you can load the same binary on both if suitably signed. If you *didn't* need the entitlement on macOS you likely have SIP disabled or custom `boot-args`.

You should also remove the "communicates-with-drivers" entitlement from the dext, and instead add "communicates-with-drivers" to the app that's going to open a user client connection. (And yes, the latter is different from macOS, where the *dext* requires a [different] entitlement to allow user client access.)